# VueJS Button inside Div with Link also triggers href link

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My html

```
<a href="/someplace">      
  <div>
    <vuecomp></vuecomp>
    <span>Click row for more info</span>
  </div>
</a>
```

Then Vue component as such...

```
<template>
  <div @click.stop="doAction">
  </div>
</template>
```

When `doAction` is called it ALSO triggers the `<a href="">` from it's parent div.
How do I stop it from doing this?
I don't want the parent div to become part of the component, it's just a table view.
I've tried `@click.stop` and passing `doAction(event)` with `event.stopPropagation();`

Any other ideas, seems like a simple thing to have a button on a click row using vuejs?

Comment: why do you wrap and div and component inside an anchor tag??

Comment: Its a table, with more information, a row, that is clickable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an empty handler to the click event on the anchor with prevent modifier :

```
 <a href="/someplace" @click.prevent="">
```

```js
let app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",

  data() {
    return {


    };
  },
  methods: {
    doAction() {

      console.log("do action")
    }
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <a href="/someplace" @click.prevent="">
    <div>
      <div @click="doAction">
      do action
      </div>
      <span>Click row for more info</span>
    </div>
  </a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to disable the default behaviour. So you need [.prevent](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers)

```
<template>
  <div @click.prevent="doAction">
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is turn the parent `<a>` tag into a plain `<div>` and attach an event to it, using the `.self` modifier. That way the click will be handled only when you've clicked onto the parent `div` itself, and not when you've clicked on any of the child elements inside of it.

```
<div href="/someplace" @click.self="yourEventToOpenTheRow">      
  <div>
    <vuecomp></vuecomp>
    <span>Click row for more info</span>
  </div>
</div>
```